# Java : Received Exception VS Catched exception

Tags: java, exception

I need to implement **Exception management component**, in Java.

Having this class :

```
public class Foo {

   void connect(){
       // some instructions here...
   }

}
```

The specification document that I have it uses such expressions :

**1. A_Exception can be received.**

**2. B_Exception can be catched as `C_Exception<B_Exception>` .**

**Edit :**
What is the difference between a catched exception and a received exception? Some sample codes would be so helpful.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: It is unclear what you need unless you provide some context...

Comment: `What does this mean?` -- you tell me.

Comment: There is no such thing called `Received Exception`, AFAIK. Can you clarify what exactly do you mean by it?

Comment: s,catched,caught,g. Also, your point 2 makes no sense: `C_Exception<B_Exception>` has no meaning in Java.

Comment: @fge Well, that is pseudo-code and not code. So I wonder about how to implement things in Java..

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ, Ok sir, I'll clarify with the person who wrote the documentation about his meaning. I remark that everybody here has confusion like me.

Answer (score 0):

`Exception` what will going to be handle is depends on the context. Importantly Checked Exception can be handle. You have to provide the context for this case. Normally `NullPointerException` not going to handle and will code the way not occur `NPE`.

Comment: Do you mean that only checked Exceptions that we can catch? Also, is handling an exception the same as catching it?

Comment: @user3169231 yes, only checked exception that can handle.